# Open twitter from android app

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, android-browser

From my android app, I want to open a link to Twitter page (in browser). I did the same thing with Facebook using this :

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

 try {
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/id"));
 } catch (Exception e) {
return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/name"));
 }
}
```

Is there anyway to do the same thing with Twitter?